# Make a context-free grammar and balance parentheses

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I need to construct a context-free grammar for the alphabet {a,),(} with balanced parentheses.

I am unsure what exactly it means to balance the parentheses and then how I go about constructing a context free grammar for it. If anyone could write down the steps for this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a rough recursive explanation, balance of the parenthesis usually means that any word, if restricted to parenthesis, either

1. starts with opening brackets and ends with as many closing brackets;
2. is a concatenation of such words;
3. is obtained from such words by putting an opening bracket to the front and a closing one to the end.

This idea can be formalized into a context free grammar as follows.

```
starting symbol: E
terminal symbols: a,(,)
E => a
E => Ea
E => (E)
E => EE
```

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) explanation, *context free* here means that the left-hand sides of the production rules contain no terminal symbols and exactly one non-terminal symbol.

Comment: You can simplify the last rule into `E => EE`. No need to enclose `E`s with parenthesis.

Comment: @blazs Thanks for the hint.